# Handle Null Values when Applying Functions to Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spacy

I am attempting to use the spaCy library to classify cities (or not cities) in a dataframe column. My dataframe is as follows:

```
    City Match eLocations Match Country Match Region Match CountryCity Match  Null Count  Null Percent
0  Los Angeles       Long Beach    Long Beach   Long Beach       Los Angeles           0           0.0
2       Santos           Santos        Santos       Santos            Santos           0           0.0
5          NaN          Stewart       Stewart      Stewart               NaN           2          40.0
7          NaN           Meling        Meling       Meling               NaN           2          40.0
```

I am trying to create an additional column called "Spacy Type" based on the type given to me by the library. My initial function looks like:

```py
def setSpace(cellValue):
    doc1 = nlp(cellValue)
    for ent in doc1.ents:
        print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
        return ent.label_


matchCols['Spacey type'] = matchCols['City Match'].apply(setSpace)

#### OUTOUT:

(Los Angeles,)
Los Angeles 0 11 GPE
()

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Where `nlp` is the processor from spacy that classifies something as a city, company, person, etc. However, running that, I keep getting `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()` which makes sense because 2 of the rows contain null values. How can I handle these null values? I cannot, for the life of me, get around this error. I have tried a couple other ways as well:

```py
def setSpace(cellValue):
    doc1 = nlp(cellValue)
    print(doc1.ents)
    gen = (ent for ent in doc1.ents if len(ent) > 0)
    for ent in gen:
        print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
        return ent.label_


matchCols['Spacey type'] = matchCols['City Match'].apply(setSpace)

##### AND ....


def setSpace(cellValue):
    if cellValue is "nan":
        return 0
    doc1 = nlp(cellValue)
    print(doc1.ents)
    for ent in doc1.ents:
        print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
        return ent.label_

matchCols['Spacey type'] = matchCols['City Match'].apply(setSpace)
```

How can apply my function to retrieve the types from spacy OR return a 0 if the column is null? It gets through Los Angeles fine, but gets tripped up after that as Santos returns nothing from spacy (as it should) and then the NaN values are passed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.isna()` to check if the value of a single cell is null. (docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.isna('dog')
False

>>> pd.isna(pd.NA)
True
```